# how would i order my sql output getting the newest at the top but allso keep the same message id together

Tags: sql, mysql, sql-order-by

so i am creating a kind of chat and all the messages are saved on the database but to group them up for the user i want them to be grouped comming out when using my select statement but with the newest first followed by every other message from that group(MessageChainId) but i cant seem to find a way to do that

this is my current sql statement:

```
SELECT nc.MessageChainId, notifications.reciverId, notifications.id 
    FROM notifications 
    INNER JOIN notificationscontent AS nc ON notifications.notificationId = nc.id 
    INNER JOIN users AS u ON notifications.senderId = u.id
    INNER JOIN user_tokens AS ut ON ut.user_id = u.id
    WHERE notifications.reciverId = 
    (SELECT user_id 
    FROM user_tokens 
    WHERE user_token = ?)
    ORDER BY notifications.id DESC, MessageChainId
```

what i get:

| MessageChainId | id |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 7 |
| 1 | 6 |
| 3 | 5 |
| 2 | 4 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 1 | 2 |

what i expected:

| MessageChainId | id |
| --- | --- |
| **2** | **7** |
| 2 | 4 |
| **1** | **6** |
| 1 | 3 |
| 1 | 2 |
| **3** | **5** |

i allso tryed to use: ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY MessageChainId ORDER BY id DESC) AS rn

Comment: Try `MAX(id) OVER (PARTITION BY MessageChainId) desc, id desc`

Comment: Try `order by max(notifications.id) over(partition by MessageChainId), notifications.id DESC, MessageChainId`

Answer (score 0):

Use `MAX()` window function to get each MessageChainId's highest id value., order by it descending.

```
select *
from ... 
order by MAX(id) OVER (PARTITION BY MessageChainId) desc, id desc;
```

Demo at https://dbfiddle.uk/GkjNP3Fw